# What is the difference between + and %?

Tags: python, python-2.5

If I do:

```
logging.debug('subject: '+subject)
logging.debug('body: '+body)
```

then it works well.
If I replace it with:

```
logging.debug('subject: %s, body: %s' % (subject, body))
```

then I get

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How to avoid this error?

Upd. added second variable `body`. `subject` and `body` are string variables.

Comment: `+` is for concatenation and `%` is for string formatting.

Comment: What version of Python?

Comment: Could you post the output of `print subject` (or `print(subject)` if in Python 3.x)?

Comment: What kind of value is stored in the `subject` variable? Is it a string or something else?

Comment: Putting `subject` in parentheses makes it a tuple.

Comment: No, a bare parenthesis is used for grouping and does not make something a tuple. You would have to use `(subject,)` to make a tuple.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, Python 2.5

Comment: @Code-Guru, yes, it is string with Cyrillic symbols

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how i would use it:

```
logging.debug(u'subject: %s', subject)
```

In your case `subject` seems to be unicode. So the format should also be unicode.

When you do `'subject: '+subject`, if one of the operands is unicode, the other is converted to unicode automatically.

Pay attention that i did `debug(u'subject: %s', subject)` instead of `debug(u'subject: %s' % subject)` - so the string is formatted only when logger is actually emitting a record.

Comment: Thanks, actually I've simplified my code in the question. In reality I have something like debug('subject: %s, body: %s' % (subject, body))

Comment: Also I've already tried to use `logging.debug(u'body: %s' % (body))`, still getting `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`.

Comment: `body` should be ascii or unicode. try: `logging.debug(u'body: %s' % body.decode('utf-8'))` if body is utf-8 encoded.

Comment: Thanks! Decoding of `body` helped.

Answer (score 0):

That is how it should be used (python `2.7`):

```
logging.debug('subject: %s' % subject)
```

e.g. using format specifications with `print`:

```
>>> sr = "aaaaaa"
>>> print "d%s" % s
daaaaaa
```

Comment: True, but if you were suggesting to avoid the parentheses around `subject` then it doesn't change. `'%s' % s` and `'%s' % (s)` are the same. Both in Python 2 and 3.